# How can I position an icon over an image or video?

Tags: html, css

How do I position an icon over an image or video? I want it to be on the bottom left corner of the image. When the user clicks on the download icon, a prompt appears asking if they would like to download the image.

Like so:

[image]

Relevant code

```html
<!-- font awesome CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- download icon -->
<a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog" download="new-filename"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a>

<!-- image of dog -->
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog" alt="dog">
```

Does this method also work with bootstrap 3 font-awesome? I might want to add a button like this on the bottom left corner:

[image]

I am using the FontAwesome download icon.

Bootstrap awesome font: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need a relative container around your image and then you set your icon to be position: `absolute`.

```css
.container { position: relative; }
.container img { display: block; }
.container .fa-download { position: absolute; bottom:0; left:0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
   <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300">
   <a href="dog.png" download="new-filename"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a>
</div>
```

The reason why you need you img to be `display: block` is because, by default, `img`'s are `display: inline` and your img will have a space between the bottom of it and the bottom of the container - so your download icon will appear slightly below your `img`. Setting it to `display: block` stops this.

Answer (score 11):

To overlay two elements, one approach is to make a parent [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), and then the overlay [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

In this case, this example should work, where the download icon can be any element, such as a bootstrap button.

```css
.img-download {
  position: relative;
}

.img-download > a {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- font awesome CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="img-download">
  <!-- image of dog -->
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog" width="320" height="240" alt="dog">
  
  <!-- download icon -->
  <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog" download="dog.jpg"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me add a variant, when you need to position the icon on right corner of unknown-width img, it doesn't work with previous response. Should introduce a wrapper as below:

```css
.wrapper { display: flex; justify-content: center;}    
.content { position: relative; width: max-content}
.content img { display: block; }
.content .fa-download { position: absolute; bottom:10px; right:10px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content">
     <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300">
     <a href="dog.png" download="new-filename"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this using the [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property. Try this:

```
<img style="z-index: 1;" src="dog.png" alt="dog">

<a style="z-index:2" href="dog.png" download="new-filename"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a>
```