# Creating a map with clickable icons based on a .PNG image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a png image of a map of the UK, and I want to place pin icons at coords on the map which when clicked will redirect you to a page with more info about that location.

I have tried using a `<map>` with `<area>`'s however the area elements cannot have icons as far as I can tell.

I have also tried absolutely positioning an icon on the map however as soon as I switch the resolution my positioning is ruined.

Has anyone done this before or have any ideas of how to do? Thanks.

Comment: _"I have also tried absolutely positioning an icon on the map however as soon as I switch the resolution my positioning is ruined."_ **Can you post the code that you tried?**

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show your attempt and ask something more specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508374/how-can-i-position-an-icon-over-an-image/54508593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success doing this before using absolute positioning with percentages. You just need to be quite precise with your percentage values. Here's a quick example with a PNG marker over London, it works well when I resize it:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.container img.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 8%;
}

.marker img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.marker.first {
  top: 74.5%;
  left: 78.7%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="map" src="https://geology.com/world/united-kingdom-map.gif" />
  
  <div class="marker first">
    <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/5025-200.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```